# Memória compartilhada entre processos Linux C (operações matemáticas)

Tags: c, linux, memória

Estou estudando memória compartilhada em linguagem C e preciso fazer um simples programa para que uma variável compartilhada inicie com um valor e depois o programa crie um processo filho onde a variável vai ser incrementada em 2 e depois o processo pai multiplica o valor por 4, não entendi muito bem como realizar essas operações, vi alguns exemplos na internet mas nenhum me ajudou, alguém sabe o que estou fazendo de errado ?

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 22
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>


int main(){
    //o processo pai e o processo filho compartilhem uma variável simples (por exemplo, inteiro - valor 1)
    int shrd;
    //shrd = 1;
    pid_t childpid;
    int shm_id;
    int *n;

    shm_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1024, IPC_CREAT);
         if (shm_id < 0) {
             printf("shmget error\n");
        }
    shrd = shmat(shm_id, 0, 0);

    //o processo pai imprime o valor inicial dessa variável; em seguida, cria o processo filho e espera-o
    printf("O valor da variavel compartilhada é %i\n",shrd);
    childpid = fork();
    printf("o childpid eh %i\n",childpid);
    //o processo filho acessa esta variável, realiza uma operação (por exemplo, adição - valor 2, totalizando 3), modificando o valor; em seguida, o processo filho termina
    if (childpid == 0){
        shrd+= 2;
    }
    else{
        //o processo pai realiza uma outra operação (por exemplo, multiplicação - valor 4, totalizando 12), modificando novamente o valor, e imprime novamente a variável 
        wait();
        shrd *= 4;
        printf("O valor da variavel compartilhada eh %i\n",shrd);    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: qual resultado você está tendo?

Answer (score 0):

Solução para o problema:
Acredito que o problema é que eu não estava utilizando um ponteiro para a variável que teria o endereço de memória compartilhado, quando fiz algumas pequenas modificações, tratando ela como ponteiro, eu consegui utilizá-la da forma correta, segue o código:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>


int main(){
    //o processo pai e o processo filho compartilhem uma variável simples (por exemplo, inteiro - valor 1)

    pid_t childpid;
    int shm_id; 

    shm_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1024, IPC_CREAT |  0660);
         if (shm_id < 0) {
             printf("shmget error\n");
        }
    // Agora estou tratando a variável como ponteiro, o que facilita todo o resto pelo fato de eu mencionar o endereço de memória que eu quero alterar
    int *shrd = (int*)shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0);


    *shrd = 1;


    //o processo pai imprime o valor inicial dessa variável; em seguida, cria o processo filho e espera-o
    printf("O valor inicial da variavel compartilhada é %i\n",*shrd);
    childpid = fork();
    printf("o childpid eh %i\n",childpid);
    //o processo filho acessa esta variável, realiza uma operação (por exemplo, adição - valor 2, totalizando 3), modificando o valor; em seguida, o processo filho termina
    if (childpid == 0){     
        *shrd+= 2;  

        printf("O valor da variavel compartilhada ao somar 2 eh %i\n",*shrd);    
    }
    else{
        //o processo pai realiza uma outra operação (por exemplo, multiplicação - valor 4, totalizando 12), modificando novamente o valor, e imprime novamente a variável 
        wait(NULL);     
        *shrd *= 4 ;

        printf("O valor da variavel compartilhada ao multiplicar por  4 eh %i\n",*shrd);    

    }


    return 0;
}
```